# In linux (or POSIX) function similar to win32 mem api

Tags: linux, heap-memory, posix, virtual-memory

I'm writing interpreted language on windows, and I use `PAGE_GUARD` to implement stack and `HeapCreate` / `HeapAlloc` for dynamic allocation of my language.

Maybe I'll need to port my lang to other OS.. So, In linux (or POSIX standard..), What is similar to these win32 api? (I hope they is not very different to use..)

---

Ok, see below if you don't know these win32 APIs:

`HeapCreate` - simple. Create a new heap:

```
void *mem = malloc(123); // alloc from default heap
HANDLE hHeap = HeapCreate(...); // create a new heap
void *mem2 = HeapAlloc(hHeap, some_flag, 123); // alloc from new heap
```

`PAGE_GUARD` - bit complex; it is used to implement stack. For example, there is a stack, whose max size is 5-pages. For saving memory, I'll alloc only one page and just "reserve" virtual memory address of 4 pages.

```
---------
| alloc |
---------
|reserve|
---------
|reserve|
---------
|reserve|
---------
|reserve|
---------
```

When first page of stack is used entirely, and program is about to use more stack, access violation occur. Then, I "commit" second page and continue program.

`PAGE_GUARD` is just helper to do this. (In win95, there isn't page guard so win95 perform without this helper) If I commit and mark the second page "guarded" ahead-of-time, and program use more stack, then GUARD-exception occur and OS unmark the page automatically. I have to only commit and mark the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Don't seek an exact equivalent in Linux for each functionality of Win32 that you know or want. Learn to natively think in Linux terms. Study [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) similar to yours (see [freecode](http://freecode.com/) or [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) to find some).

<sup>And yes, Posix or Linux vs Windows is very different, notably for their notion of [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), etc...</sup>

You probably want [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html); I don't know at all Windows (so I have no idea of what `HeapCreate` does).

Maybe using the lower layer of cross-platform toolkits like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (i.e. `QtCore`...) or [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) (from *Gtk* ...) might help you.

Linux [C standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) is often [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) (but you could use some other, e.g. [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/), which is very readable IMHO). It use [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and implemented by the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) (in particular, [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) is generally built above [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)...).

Take the habit of studying the source code of free software if that helps you.

BTW, for an interpreter, you could consider using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/)...

Comment: please see edit. And I know linux and win are different, and I want to know only "how to do in linux", although I hope the way is similiar to windows...

Comment: Don't hope that Linux and Windows are similar: they are not. In addition, Linux is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you can and should perhaps study the source code.

Comment: I'm not saying "win vs linux". I'm saying only "how to do in linux".. Anyway, `mmap` and `mprotect` seem to be what I find, thanks! Btw, Is there no way to create new heap? then I need to implement heap? Oh..

Comment: I don't know what you call a heap. FYI, `malloc` is using `mmap` and you could study or improve the source code of it (since it is free software).

Comment: and also thanks for recommending a good book, but It seems that there's no translation version of my language! I'm so sad..

Comment: heap : where dynamic allocation, such as `malloc`, is allocated.

Comment: Study or improve the source code of  `malloc` from the *libc* you are using (often GNU libc).